# Why isnt my Android view element rotating

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an image button inside a frame layout inside of a relative layout. I add the following to the image button `android:rotation="-90"` but the image button doesnt appear to change.
**View Hierarchy**
[image]
**XML**

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/profile_pic_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_profile_pic_btn"
    android:contentDescription="profile picture button"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_face_black_48dp"/>

<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
    android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:donut_progress="70"
    custom:donut_text_size="0dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_pic_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing, works fine for me. Could you remove all hierarchy and keep only the `ImageButton` and see what happens?

Comment: I have the whole thing in 1 framelayout now. No parents and still not working. Ill update the xml in the question.

Comment: Could you post the full xml file? I see only the children in the one you just posted. Also, try removing the `DonutProgress` and keep your hierarchy like this: Parent FrameLayout and Child ImageButton. That's all and nothing else in the xml file. Try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Could not post as comment as my rep is not there yet. Did you try it in any emulator or actual device? I copied your xml (except the circleprogress.DonutProgress stuff) and it worked in the emulator and device.

The effect is not visible in Design mode though.